# TypeError: Slackbot is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, bots, typeerror, slack, slack-api

I need your help because it's the first time that I develop a Slack bot and I don't understand why this message appear:

```
const botSlack = new Slackbot ({
                 ^

TypeError: Slackbot is not a constructor
```

Here my code : slack.js

```
const {Slackbot} = require('@slack/bolt');

const botSlack = new Slackbot({
    token : process.env.SLACK_BOT_TOKEN,
    signingSecret: process.env.SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET,
});

(async () => {
    await botSlack.start(process.env.PORT || 3000);
})();
```

Part of my package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon slack.js",
},
  "dependencies": {
    "@slack/bolt": "^3.11.0",
},
```

In the bolt documentation (https://api.slack.com/tutorials/hello-world-bolt) and others, it's the same and it's run.

Please someone can explain to me why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation has this code - `App` instead of `Slackbot`. You can rename the local variable if you want, but the import statement requires the exact name:

```js
const { App } = require('@slack/bolt');

const botSlack = new App({
  token: process.env.SLACK_BOT_TOKEN,
  signingSecret: process.env.SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET
});

(async () => {
  await botSlack.start(process.env.PORT || 3000);
})();
```

if you do want to rename the value, you can use

```js
const { App: Slackbot } = require('@slack/bolt');
```

It is more common to use import statements for this, you can still alias it using `import { App as Stackbot} from '@slack/bolt'`, see [MDN - `import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#syntax)